# Software emulated OpenGL with higher version than my graphics card supports

Tags: hardware, opengl, emulation, mesa

I have an Intel GMA 950 chipset in my netbook. I want to learn how to write OpenGL shader programs [with this fantastic tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) and therefore need OpenGL 3.3. Sadly, my graphics card only supports OpenGL 1.4.

I think that MESA can emulate OpenGL in software, so I'm wondering if it can emulate OpenGL 3.3 without any hardware accelleration (**performance is not a problem**, since this is only for learning and testing puroses, even excluding profiling).

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do here, negates any advantages you would have coding in OpenGL. OpenGL is a set of hardware calls, translating that into CPU int or fp.

Add an extra step in the CALL, SOLVE, RENDER. So it'd be CALL, TRANSCODE, SOLVE[slower], RECODE, RENDER.

The whole call solve render happens in fractions of fractions of a second, so adding in transcode, and a recode, would at least take .010 each, thereby destroying your fps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm totally aware of that. The point is to have the *opportunity* to learn by coding, not any performance. 0.1 FPS would be totally fine. But I decided to learn OpenGL 1.4 compatible shaders too (I learn 1.4 on the netbook and 3.3 on the Desktop), so it's fine that I currently have no solution for this. Still, I want to keep the question opened, maybe someone finds a solution.